# How to Get the Number of Total Rows after Applying Paging

Tags: sql-server

I'm doing paging with @skip and @take parameters. I need the number of total rows after doing paging. How can I do this as the best way in performance?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Search
    @Take       Int           = 10
    @Skip       Int           = 0
    @TotalRows  Int Out
AS

    BEGIN
    Select
                    RowNo, FirstName, LastName
                From
                    (
                        Select Row_Number()Over(Order By Id) As [RowNo],
                            FirstName,
                            LastName    
                        From Users                  
                    ) tblTemp
                Where RowNo > @Skip And RowNo <= @Take + @Skip

                Set @TotalRows = ??? -- I need the number of total rows after applying paging. How can I do this?
    END
```

Comment: Please tag your DBMS, eg MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle

Comment: @SteveLovell, thanks. I edited the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@@ROWCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql)

procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Search
    @Take       Int           = 10,
    @Skip       Int           = 0,
    @TotalRows  Int Out
AS
BEGIN
    Select
        RowNo, 
        FirstName, 
        LastName
    From (
        Select 
            Row_Number()Over(Order By Id) As [RowNo],
            FirstName,
            LastName    
        From Users                  
    ) tblTemp
    Where RowNo > @Skip And RowNo <= @Take + @Skip

    Set @TotalRows = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

You can call the proc like;

```
declare @total_rows int;
exec search 10, 0, @total_rows output
select @total_rows
```

Comment: I did what you said before and always @TotalRows is 10, so your answer is not correct.

Comment: `@total_rows output` is this the way you used the variable in the procedure??? how did you call the procedure search>>